# How to create function that returns data frame from two imported csv files

Tags: r

How would I create a function that returns 4 columns from from two separate files.

The files are:
Incident: ID, Incident.Number, Date.Time, Street.Name, City, State, Station.Responding, Zip.

SalaryData: CalendarYear, EmployeeName, Department, JobTitle, AnnualRate, Regularrate, OvertimeRate, IncentiveAllowance, Other, YeartoDate.

I want to create a function that returns a dataframe with 4 columns:
1) Year type character
2) #ofIncidents
3) TotalWages
4) CostperIncident

I am not worried about how to calculate the columns, just how to write a function that reads two files and creates a data frame with the 4 columns. Just the basic order or syntax that would get me started.

If more information is needed I will gladly provide it.

I sincerely appreciate any help to get me started.

Thank you.

Comment: How are the two data frames being combined?

Comment: See `read.files`, `lapply`, `sapply`, `do.call`, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r

Comment: I was trying to combined them with the year. However, one is date.time (yyyy/mm/dd) and the other is Year(yyyy). So, I am trying to create a separate column in Incident that is just Year(yyyy), then I will combine them.

Comment: Please read the info about how to give a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: Relax. Relax. Relax.